# How to use MonoDevelop pc files with UNIX convention relative pathnames?

Tags: ubuntu, mono, pkg-config

On my Ubuntu Linux 16.04 Lenovo desktop , I am using MonoDevelop 5.10 with the Xamarin ASP.NET plugin for  development and production environments.

I am using *.pc files with Unix convention full absolution pathnames to add external C# dll references to  a large and complex ASP.NET csproj project which I imported from Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 for Windows 7.

The problem with my  19 pc files in /usr/lib/pkgconfig is that I have to redo them to change the full absolute pathnames for the external C# dll references every time I change my hosting directory name.

How could I use MonoDevelop pc files with UNIX convention relative pathnames? Do I need to add some more key value pairs to my csproj file or Web.config file?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify relative path names for dll's in Monodevelop's pc files  with respect to $(PROJECT_DIR)$ where PROJECT_DIR is where your csproj resides.PROJECT_DIR is my "invention". It cannot be found in your csproj file.

Comment: You need to delete existing HintPath's inherited from imported csproj's. Please let me know if you have any problems by leaving a comment here. Thank you.